# Sort a Pandas dataframe by frequency and length

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that contains a list of atmospheric river (AR) landfalls. Each AR has an associated date (the date of initial landfall), incremented by 6 hour time periods. This list also includes a column that tells what number the AR is throughout a ~40 year period. Most of the ARs last longer than one 6 hour time period and thus have the same number of AR over the time period. In my case, I want to order the ARs by how long they lasted, while maintaining the first date the AR made landfall.

```
number of AR   Year   Month   Day   Hour 
1651           1979   1       5     18
1651           1979   1       6     0
1651           1979   1       6     06
1651           1979   1       6     12
1651           1979   1       6     18
1652           1979   1       8     06
1652           1979   1       8     12
1652           1979   1       8     18
```

Ideally I would have a new dataframe that looked something like this:

```
number of AR     Frequency    Year   Month   Day   Hour 
1651             5            1979   1       5     18
1652             3            1979   1       8     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a groupby to take the first of each `AR`, then `join` with the value counts. This implies that your dataframe is sorted by `Year`, then `Month`, then `Day` (done below with `sort_values`):

```
new_df = df.sort_values(['Year','Month', 'Day']).groupby(['number of AR']).first()

new_df = new_df.join(df['number of AR'].value_counts().to_frame('frequency'))


>>> new_df
              Year  Month  Day  Hour  frequency
number of AR                                   
1651          1979      1    5    18          5
1652          1979      1    8     6          3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want the first occurrence of each unique "number of AR" joined with the length associated with that.

```
df.groupby('number of AR').first().merge(
df.groupby('number of AR').apply(len).rename("Frequency").to_frame(), 
left_on='number of AR', right_index=True)

#            Year   Month   Day Hour    Frequency
#number of AR                   
#1651       1979    1       5   18      5
#1652       1979    1       8   6       3
```

If you don't actually want the first, you should first sort by the value you care about before calling `.first()`.